# JavaFX: Not sure what I'm looking for

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

So this is what I'm looking to do. I'm not sure what it is called so bear with me.

I originally thought it might be a button but now I'm not so sure.

I'm looking to create an input of the user clicking/touch an icon that opens up an area/portion of the app.

The best way to describe this is describing another program that does what I'm looking for. In windows explorer you can go to the side and tap on the folder to see all the sub-folders in that folder.

What I'm looking for is the action/event that allows a user to click on a word or the plus sign like:

(+)Christmas

When they click on the word of the plus sign, the (+) becomes a (-) and opens up all the stuff inside, like:

(-)Christmas
Then it shows several items below that now can be accessed.

When you click on the (-) it closes up everything and returns the status back to (+)

This is just an example.

Does anyone know how/what this is and how to implement it in JavaFX/Java for an application?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`Accordion`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html) or [`TreeView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html)?

Comment: yes TreeView thats it i believe , thank you for the help

Comment: now in treeview can you open and close the items so that only the title is visible

Comment: Tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-view.htm).